# Auto-refresh QSqlTableModel/QTableView when the underlying SQL table is changed from outside of my application

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I use `QSqlTableModel` and `QTableView` to display a table from an underlying SQLite database. At the same time, the table can be changed outside of my application. When that happens, I need to detect this and refresh the `QSqlTableModel` and `QTableView`.

Currently, the `QSqlTableModel` and `QTableView` do not detect the changes at all, until some user action forces a refresh, such as editing a field. So how can I implement this?

Right now I'm thinking about polling, but I'm not sure what to poll for changes, and especially how to do it with minimum overhead. Do I just run a `COUNT` SQL query? What if an element has been added but another removed? I'd rather not force-refresh if there are no changes to the table.

So what would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no mechanism that allows multiple processes to communicate in real time.

The easiest way to detect changes in a database file is the [file change counter](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#chngctr).

However, if you can get all applications to cooperate, you should use some other mechanism to send notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for you. Try to use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) to detect any file changes.

```
    QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
    watcher->addPath("path");
    connect(watcher,SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)),SLOT(updateData()));
```

Slot:

```
void QSSViewer::updateData()
{
    qDebug() << "changed";
}
```

I tested it on my computer and when I change database with another program, `QFileSystemWatcher` catched this changes every time. So you can do all needed actions inside `updateData()` slot.