# QSqlDatabase and QTableView do not sync( SQLite)

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, pyqt, pyside

I am using an SQLite database with `QSqlDatabase` and show data using 2 `QTableView` with `QSqlTableModels`.

My application inserts data into tables using `QSqlQuery` but the tables do not update to display new data (the no of rows displayed are not changed for example). I was expecting new data to be automatically reflected in the `QTableView`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That there's no magic going on; SQLite does not push any notifications to Qt in order to have such views to update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-refresh QSqlTableModel/QTableView when the underlying SQL table is changed from outside of my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365301/auto-refresh-qsqltablemodel-qtableview-when-the-underlying-sql-table-is-changed)

Comment: A timer doing a select query on timeout event could do the trick and doesn't come that costly.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not supported by Qt. When a table is altered, there is no notification mechanism to update the model and view automatically. Although you can do it in PostgreSQL in some way as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916570/is-there-any-qt-signal-for-sql-database-change/22919225#22919225) but in SQLite you need to query the database periodically and update the view which is costly. An other option is to use `QFileSystemWatcher` to catch file changes and update the view on time:

```
QFileSystemWatcher *databaseWatcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
databaseWatcher->addPath("Path/To/database.sqlite");
QObject::connect(databaseWatcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(refreshView()));
```

Now it watches the database file and when ever it's changed by an external process or by your self, `fileChanged` signal is emitted and `refreshView` slot is called in which you should update the model and view.